# Hook some code after body tags

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a wp plugin and i am trying to hook some code after the body..
MY code bellow hooked at the very top and not after the body tags.

Also i tried to echo all the code bellow but nothing happend also..

my code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId  : 'xxxxxx',
          status : true, 
          cookie : true, 
          xfbml  : true  
        });
      };

      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
FB.init({appId: "xxxxxxxx", status: true, cookie: true});
  function share_me() {
    FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
      app_id: 'xxxxxxxxx',
      link: 'http://www.thesite.com',
      picture: 'http://www.thesite.com/image.gif',
      name: 'Pynchon\'s Edge',
      caption: 'Amazing',
      description: 'The novel is due Fall 2013'
    },
    function(response){
      if(response && response.post_id) {

      }
      else {

      }
    });
  }
</script>
<?  
}
add_action('after_body', 'sb_fb');
do_action('after_body', 'sb_fb');
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is your `sb_fb` function?

Comment: in my plugin.. i created a folder myplugin and i created a file myplugin.php and inside i have all my functions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
add_action('after_body', 'sb_fb');
do_action('after_body', 'sb_fb');
```

with

`add_action('wp_footer', 'sb_fb');`

in your plugin file.

Comment: And how is possible please to run once a function when my plugin is activated? I want to create a table once when the plugin is activated for the first time..